# PHP: How to modify working email script to run on own server (PHP mail server setup on LAMP server)

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, html-email

I am using lines like the below to send emails after submitting a form on my website.
So far everyhing works as intended.

Now I would like to set up my own server and would like to avoid setting up an email client on this server.
**Can someone tell me what I have to add here to set this up to use a mailing server ?**
Does this work using IP addresses or do I need an extra PHP file for this kind of set up ?

**Note:** My emails will only contain text and some basic HTML, no attachments.

I am pretty new to PHP and was hoping to get some help in getting started with this here.

**My PHP (shortened):**

```
// get submitted form data
$postData = $_POST;
// retrieve some post data to include in email

unset($postData);

// prepare email
$to = 'someone@mail.com';   
$subject = 'Some text';

$emailBody = '<html><body>Some HTML text</body></html>';    
$headers = 'From: Someone <someone@mail.com>' . PHP_EOL .
    'Cc: someoneelse@mail.com <someoneelse@mail.com>' . PHP_EOL .
    'Reply-To: noreply@mail.com <noreply@mail.com>' . PHP_EOL .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();                                

// set content-type header for sending HTML email
$headers .= "\r\n". "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers .= "\r\n". "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8";

// send email
$mail = mail($to, $subject, $emailBody, $headers);

if($mail) {
    header('Location: support.php?status=emailSent');
}
```

Many thanks in advance, 
Tom

Comment: @esqew: Thanks for this. It seems this is specific for Rackspace. I have a LAMP server so right now I have only Linux, Apache, MariaDB and PHP installed there.

Comment: Use PHPMailer; it's much more flexible, whatever your setup. You've not shown all of your code, but it's very easy to make a simple contact form become an accidental spam gateway or facilitate header injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your php.ini file an look for "[mail function]".  You can specify your SMTP server/port/credentials there.

```
[mail function]    
SMTP = smtp.example.com
smtp_port = 25
username = info@example.com
password = yourmailpassord
sendmail_from = info@example.com
```

Here you can set it up like your email client on whatever machine you have email set up.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. When PHP is installed on the server does the php.ini file automatically get installed there too ? Sorry for this beginner's question, I am new to PHP and I haven't used this so far.

Comment: On hosted servers, you normally don't have access to php.ini.  In some cases, you are able to customize some php.ini settings using cpanel or an ".htaccess" file at the root of the site.  You will need to ask your hosting provider which settings are customizable through .htaccess or cpanel.

Comment: Thanks for that too. That helps a lot.